# Proposition 1.6.6, Etale Cohomology theory, Lei Fu

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, flatness, etale-cohomology, descent

I have difficulties in understanding a gap of the proof of proposition 1.6.6 in Etale Cohomology Theory written by Lei Fu.

$\mathrm{Proposition} 1.6.6$ 
Let $g:S'\rightarrow S$ be a quasi-compact faithfully flat morphism, and let $\mathcal F$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_S$-module. Then $g^* \mathcal F$ is locally of finite type(resp. locally of finite presentation,resp. locally free of finite rank) if and only if $\mathcal F$ is so.

The author reduces the proof to the case where both S' and S are affine, but the detail is left to the reader.

How can I confirm this reduction?  S' and S seem to be schemes but not necessarily Noetherian.

Comment: I would cover $S$ with open affines (which are in particular quasi-compact). Their preimages are open and quasi-compact, since $g$ is quasi-compact. Then we cover these preimages with open affines which can be done by finitely many (quasi-compactness). Doesn't this work?

Comment: @PaulK I was thinking about the same thing, but I have no idea about how to use faithfully flatness. It seems for me that there's no morphism like $\mathrm{Spec}A'\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec} A$ where $A'$ is faithfully flat over $A$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @PaulK We may suppose $S=\mathrm{Spec}A$, $S'$ can be covered by finite affine schemes $\mathrm{Spec} A'_i$ and g is faithfully flat. Then we need to reduce the case $S'=\mathrm{Spec} A' \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec} A$ is faithfully flat, but $A'_i$ is not necessarily faithfully flat over A. So, where can I use the case where S' and S are affine?

Comment: Now I got it. How about looking at the disjoint union of $A_i'$ which is an affine scheme by finiteness? Maybe that works?

Comment: @PaulK Thank you for your great help. I carefully read the proof of affine case and realized that it only proves that if A' is faithfully flat over A, then $M\otimes A' $ is finitely generated (resp. of finite presentation) $\Rightarrow M$ is so. But I believe that if there exists $\mathrm{Spec} A_1, \mathrm{Spec} A_2 \subset \mathrm{Spec} A$ such that $\mathrm{Spec} A=\mathrm{Spec} A_1\cup \mathrm{Spec} A_2$ and $M\otimes A_i$ is finitely generated(resp. of finite presentation), then $M\otimes (A_1\oplus A_2)$ is so as $A_1\oplus A_2$-module. I think this and your idea complete the proof.